# yii2 model find with relation

Tags: join, model-view-controller, yii2, relational-database

I have the following query

```
    $model_company = Members_companies::find()
            ->select(['members_companies.id', 'companies.name'])
            ->leftJoin('companies', 'members_companies.company = companies.id ')
            ->where(['members_companies.member' => $member])
            ->orderBy(['companies.name' => SORT_ASC])
            ->all();
```

The query result shows no errors. Furthermore, the result shows also the right records. But there are no `companies.name` column with results available. 
If I do the same query in `MYSQL Workbench` or `PHPMyAdmin` the query shows also the `companies.name` column with values.

This query is the same result:

```
$model_company = Members_companies::find()
        ->select(['members_companies.id', 'companies.name'])
        ->leftJoin('companies', ['members_companies.company' => 'companies.id'])
        ->where(['members_companies.member' => $member])
        ->orderBy(['companies.name' => SORT_ASC])
        ->all();
```

Comment: And how you access `companies.name`?

Comment: In the view, but I also trace the process with debugging and I see the result immediately before it ends in the view.

Comment: It's because it's simpy "name" in result array in view use as and desired column name like "companies.name as companies_name".

Comment: I didn't asked `where`, i asked `how`.

Comment: What @Yupik asks you is how do you access column. Something like $model_company[0]['id'] or similar. I just asumed (wrongly) that you used asArray() in your query in my comment.

Comment: Iam not sure whether I understand it right, but the first access where I access the query is in the next step with $companies = ArrayHelper::map($model_company,'id','name'); And of course this is not working because 'name' is not known. $model_company[0]['id'] is working $model_company[0]['name'] ends up in Error 'Getting unknown property:frontend\models\Members_companies::name'.

Comment: You are trying to map an object in a array way. Add asArray() before all() in query if you use it as array

Comment: I've added asArray like you recommended Vladimir, but $model_company[0]['name'] stays null! Normal SQL query in tools shows right results: SELECT members_companies.id, companies.name
FROM members_companies
LEFT JOIN companies on members_companies.company = companies.id
WHERE members_companies.member = 3
order by companies.name;

Comment: make sure you have a rule for `name` attribute in `companies` model.

Comment: show us var_dump($model_company)

Comment: Yes there is a rule [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 100], in Companies model

Comment: var_dump:   0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'name' => null
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'name' => null

Comment: var_dump($member)?

Comment: var_dump($member): int 3 - ..and the id's of the results are correct for member '3'.

Comment: See in debuger (Database Queries tab) what gets executed.

Comment: The debugged SQL query: SELECT `members_companies`.`id`, `companies`.`name` FROM `members_companies` LEFT JOIN `companies` ON `members_companies`.`company`=:qp0 WHERE `members_companies`.`member`=:qp1 ORDER BY `companies`.`name`

Comment: Are you using ->leftJoin('companies', 'members_companies.company = companies.id ')? Don't use ->leftJoin('companies', ['members_companies.company = companies.id '])

Comment: No I work with the last statement ->leftJoin('companies', ['members_companies.company' => 'companies.id'])

Comment: Change it and try it!

Comment: You are right Vladimir! I will post the whole statement as new answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [docs for on condition](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#join()-detail), you should specify column to column matching conditions as string.

So if we update your on condition to be string rather than an array, it should work. Updated Code Below:

```
$model_company = Members_companies::find()
        ->select(new yii\db\Expression('{{%members_companies}}.[[id]], {{%companies}}.[[name]]'])
        ->leftJoin('{{%companies}} c', '{{%members_companies}}.[[company]]=c.[[id]]')
        ->where(['{{%members_companies}}.[[member]]' => $member])
        ->orderBy(['c.[[name]]' => SORT_ASC])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

Comment: It is necessary to include ->asArray(). This was usually missing in the first statement! thx!

Comment: yes it is, if you want result set as an array like your case, updated my answer

Comment: I removed my answer, to prevent from double post and credit your answer! Thanks to you and Vladimir for the sustainable effort!

Comment: It's always good to wrap you `table_names` in the query with `{{%}}` and columns with `[[]]` when working with raw table names so that if an alias is used for the tables in the config, it should be appended to them.just updated your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting result as `Members_companies` as object. so it not include companies name, if you want company name easiest way is get query result as array instead of object as below

```
$model_company = Members_companies::find()
        ->select('members_companies.id,companies.name')
        ->leftJoin('companies', 'members_companies.company = companies.id ')
        ->where(['members_companies.member' => $member])
        ->orderBy(['companies.name' => SORT_ASC])
        ->asArray();
        ->all();
```

Comment: I did it already, like you and Vladimir recommended. Result is  array (size=2)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'name' => null

Comment: ->select('members_companies.id,companies.name') Try this

Comment: also with this change of the select the result stays the same  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'name' => null
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'name' => null

Comment: have your both tables contain column name ?

Comment: ->select('members_companies.id,companies.name as company_name')  Try this

Comment: No, there is only one column with 'name' and this column is in table companies.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new public property $cname in Members_companies model. and then
add alias for companies.name column like this:

```
$model_company = Members_companies::find()
        ->select('members_companies.id, companies.name as cname')
        ->leftJoin('companies', ['members_companies.company' => 'companies.id'])
        ->where(['members_companies.member' => $member])
        ->orderBy(['companies.name' => SORT_ASC])
        ->all();
```

You'll see cname property containing the company name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have relation with companies model, you can write query like this

```
$model_company = Members_companies::find()
        ->select('members_companies.id, companies.name as cname')
        ->joinWith(['companies'])
        ->where(['members_companies.member' => $member])
        ->orderBy(['companies.name' => SORT_ASC])
        ->all();
```

Source from https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/how-to-include-relation-of-relation-in-find-model/84982/2